# What is the meaning of in-place in dropout

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, dropout

```
def dropout(input, p=0.5, training=True, inplace=False)
```

> inplace: If set to `True`, will do this operation in-place.

I would like to ask what is the meaning of in-place in dropout. What does it do?
Any performance changes when performing these operation?

Thanks

Comment: [What is `in-place operation`?](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/what-is-in-place-operation/16244)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Keeping `inplace=True` will itself drop few values in the tensor `input` itself, whereas if you keep `inplace=False`, you will to save the result of `droput(input)` in some other variable to be retrieved.

Example:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
inp = torch.tensor([1.0, 2.0, 3, 4, 5])

outplace_dropout = nn.Dropout(p=0.4)
print(inp)
output = outplace_dropout(inp)
print(output)
print(inp) # Notice that the input doesn't get changed here


inplace_droput = nn.Dropout(p=0.4, inplace=True)
inplace_droput(inp)
print(inp) # Notice that the input is changed now
```

PS: This is not related to what you have asked but try not using `input` as a variable name since `input` is a Python keyword. I am aware that Pytorch docs also does that, and it is kinda funny.